# Are English judges using "linguistics" wrongly, not "language" as adjective?

Tags: word-choice, legalese

In quotes below, I don't feel English judges are using ["linguistic"](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/lucy_search_1.cgi?query=linguistic+NOT+belgian&datelow=&datehigh=&sort=rank&highlight=1&mask_path=uk%2Fcases%2FUKHL+uk%2Fcases%2FUKSC+uk%2Fcases%2FUKPC&mask_path=uk%2Fcases%2FUKHL&mask_path=uk%2Fcases%2FUKSC&mask_path=uk%2Fcases%2FUKPC) correctly, because they're not doing linguistics! They're referring just English language! "language" is more correct right?

[*Linguistics. An Introduction to Language and Communication*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262513706) (2010 6 ed). p 5.

> What is linguistics, then? Fundamentally, the field is concerned with
>   the nature of language and (linguistic) communication. It is apparent that
>   people have been fascinated with language and communication for thousands
>   of years, yet in many ways we are only beginning to understand the
>   complex nature of this aspect of human life. If we ask, What is the nature
>   of language? or How does communication work? we quickly realize that
>   these questions have no simple answers and are much too broad to be
>   answered in a direct way. Similarly, questions such as What is energy?
>   or What is matter? cannot be answered in a simple fashion, and indeed
>   research in physics is carried out in numerous subfields, some of which involve
>   investigating the nature of energy and matter. Linguistics is no different:
>   the field as a whole represents an attempt to break down the broad
>   questions about the nature of language and communication into smaller,

[K, Petitioner [1998] UKHL 54 (03 December 1998)](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/format.cgi?doc=/uk/cases/UKHL/1998/1999_SC_HL_1.html&query=linguistics)

> **LORD HOFFMANN** —My Lords, on a reading of the Act as a whole and in particular the conjunction of paras (a) and (b) of sec 35B(8), it is clear that para (a) contains a [image]**linguistic** error or infelicity. The indicative ‘do not apply’ should have been the conditional ‘would not apply’, implying the condition ‘if a community care order is made’. The words are wrong but the meaning which they convey in their contextual setting is clear. I know of no principle of statutory construction which prevents a court from giving effect to the meaning of the Act and would therefore dismiss the appeal.

[*Secretary of State for Trade and Industry v Frid* [2004] UKHL 24 (13 May 2004)](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/format.cgi?doc=/uk/cases/UKHL/2004/24.html&query=linguistics)

> - My Lords, so far I have been concentrating upon the effect of the words "mutual debts". The words "or other mutual dealings" was added for the first time by the Bankruptcy Act 1869. These words, and particularly the word "other" create what the High Court of Australia in *Gye v McIntyre* 171 CLR 609, 623 tactfully called "a [image]**linguistic**[image] problem". The language suggests that the previous words "mutual credits, mutual debts" must be qualified by a requirement that the credits or debts can in some sense be described as "mutual dealings". But all the authorities since the 1869 Act have been unanimous in saying that Parliament in no way intended to restrict the ambit of the original formula. On the contrary, the purpose was to broaden it. In *Booth v Hutchinson* (1872) LR 15 Eq 30, 35, Malins V-C said that the additional words "were intended to give a more extended right of set-off than previously existed" and in *Peat v Jones & Co* (1881) 8 QBD 147, 149 Sir George Jessel MR said:
>
> "Now the enactment as to 'mutual credits' is a very old one, first appearing in 5 Geo 2, c 30, but the whole tendency of the subsequent legislation, as of the legislation respecting proveable debts, has been to extend the principle upon which it is founded."
>
> - What then is the answer to the "[image]**linguistic** problem" identified by the High Court of Australia in *Gye v McIntyre* (1991) 171 CLR 609, 623? That court gave a clear answer:
>
> " 'Credits' and 'debts' will ordinarily represent the outcome of dealings rather than the dealings themselves. Conversely, 'dealings' commonly do not, of themselves as distinct from their outcome, represent credits or debts susceptible of direct set-off… The requirement of mutuality in respect of "other…dealings", as distinct from 'credits' or 'debts' susceptible of immediate set-off, is directed not so much to the relationship between the dealings as such but to the relationship between the claims which have arisen from them."

[*Chartbrook Ltd v Persimmon Homes Ltd & Ors* [2009] UKHL 38 (1 July 2009)](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/format.cgi?doc=/uk/cases/UKHL/2009/38.html&query=linguistics)

> 14. There is no dispute that the principles on which a contract (or any other instrument or utterance) should be interpreted are those summarised by the House of Lords in *Investors Compensation Scheme Ltd v West Bromwich Building Society* [[1998] 1 WLR 896](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/redirect.cgi?path=/uk/cases/UKHL/1997/28.html), 912-913. They are well known and need not be repeated. It is agreed that the question is what a reasonable person having all the background knowledge which would have been available to the parties would have understood them to be using the language in the contract to mean. The House emphasised that “we do not easily accept that people have made [image]**linguistic**[image] mistakes, particularly in formal documents” (similar statements will be found in *Bank of Credit and Commerce International SA v Ali* [[2002] 1 AC 251](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/redirect.cgi?path=/uk/cases/UKHL/2001/8.html), 269, *Kirin-Amgen Inc v Hoechst Marion Roussel Ltd* [[2005] RPC 169](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/redirect.cgi?path=/uk/cases/UKHL/2004/46.html), 186 and *Jumbo King Ltd v Faithful Properties Ltd* [(1999) 2 HKCFAR 279](http://www.hklii.org/hk/jud/en/hkcfa/1999/FACV000007_1999.html), 296) but said that in some cases the context and background drove a court to the conclusion that “something must have gone wrong with the language". In such a case, the law did not require a court to attribute to the parties an intention which a reasonable person would not have understood them to have had.
> 15. It clearly requires a strong case to persuade the court that something must have gone wrong with the language and the judge and the majority of the Court of Appeal did not think that such a case had been made out. On the other hand, Lawrence Collins LJ thought it had. It is, I am afraid, not unusual that an interpretation which does not strike one person as sufficiently irrational to justify a conclusion that there has been a [image]**linguistic**[image] mistake will seem commercially absurd to another: compare the *Kirin-Amgen* case [[2005] RPC 169](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/redirect.cgi?path=/uk/cases/UKHL/2004/46.html) at pp. 189-190. Such a division of opinion occurred in the *Investors Compensation Scheme* case itself. The subtleties of language are such that no judicial guidelines or statements of principle can prevent it from sometimes happening. It is fortunately rare because most draftsmen of formal documents think about what they are saying and use language with care. But this appears to be an exceptional case in which the drafting was careless and no one noticed.

[*The Mayor's Office for Policing and Crime v Mitsui Sumitomo Insurance Co (Europe) Ltd & Ors* [2016] UKSC 18 (20 April 2016)](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/format.cgi?doc=/uk/cases/UKSC/2016/18.html&query=linguistics)

> 9.  In support of its view that the 1886 Act provides for the recovery of consequential losses, the Court of Appeal began with a [image]**linguistic**[image] analysis of section 2(1). It pointed out that the words, which I have emphasised in para 7 above, compensated for loss "sustained ... by such injury, stealing, or destruction". This was loss that was caused by (i) damage to or destruction of a building, or (ii) damage, destruction or stealing of property in the building. Such loss could as a matter of [image]**linguistic**[image] analysis include consequential losses, such as the loss of rent while an owner repaired his building. Secondly, the other provisions in the 1886 Act, including the now-repealed preamble (which I discuss in para 31 below), did not militate against this view. Case law on predecessor legislation suggested that remedial statutes should be given a liberal interpretation. Thirdly, that case law, which I discuss in paras 20 to 23 below, also suggested a principle that the relevant community, which was then the hundred, stood as sureties for the trespassers. There was no reason to think that a rioter would not have been liable in tort for consequential losses before Parliament legislated in 1714. Thus the local authority incurred such liability under statute. The 1886 Act did not depart from what the Court of Appeal described as "the fundamental 'standing as sureties' principle".

[*London Borough of Southwark & Anor v Transport for London* [2018] UKSC 63 (5 December 2018)](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/format.cgi?doc=/uk/cases/UKSC/2018/63.html&query=linguistics)

> 17.  It will be immediately apparent that there are significant [image]**linguistic**[image] similarities and differences between section 7 of the 1936 Act and section 228 of the 1959 Act. What was previously called “the road” is now called “the highway”. Whereas, in the 1936 Act, the transfer both of the road and other property (including land) was all regulated by the condition that it had been vested in the former highway authority “for the purposes of their functions in relation to the highway” that condition is, in the 1959 Act, applied in the same language to other property including land, but not in express terms to the highway. Rather, the condition relating to the highway itself is that it is transferred “in so far as, immediately before the said date, it was vested in the former highway authority”. There is also, in section 228(6), a provision for reverse transfer where a trunk road ceases to be a trunk road but it is not suggested that this significantly affects the present dispute.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As a reminder, questions are expected to demonstrate some initial research effort. For example, looking up *linguistic* in a dictionary would show that a common definitive of the word is *of or related to language*, not merely related to the field of linguistics. Additionally, in a legal context, *linguistic* may have a special usage that varies from the common usage.

Comment: "linguistics" as a noun is not the same as "linguistic" as an adjective.